# CSS Grid : Align image with legends

Tags: html, css

I have a grid layout and I want the pictures and the legends to be align horizontaly.

But, if all the legends haven't the same size, the first element of the new line will be align to the right insted of the left...
Can I acheive something like this only in CSS/HTML ?

https://jsfiddle.net/8202x060/

```
  .grid12-2 {
    width: 14.66%;
}

img {
    max-width:100%;
}

.grid12-1, .grid12-2, .grid12-25, .grid12-3, .grid12-4, .grid12-5, .grid12-6, .grid12-7, .grid12-8, .grid12-9, .grid12-10, .grid12-11, .grid12-12, .grid-full, .grid-col2-sidebar, .grid-col2-main {
    display: inline;
    float: left;
    margin-left: 1%;
    margin-right: 1%;
}

<div class="grid12-2 mobile-grid">
    <a class="open-popup-link" href="#popup-feu">    
        <img src="http://lorempixel.com/g/200/200" />
    <p class="project-name">The Dialogue of Fire</p>
    </a>
</div>
```

Comment: you could try using flexbox

Comment: The 'legend' is the paragraph with the class project-name? You mean aligned below the image but the text is on the right?

Comment: You can add `min-height` to .grid12-2 which will make sure that all the sections are at least the same height and cause them to fall in line

Comment: add custom css & mobile-grid{display:inline-block; float: inherit;vertical-align:top;}

Comment: can you use: `display:table` for the container and `display:table-cell` for the items? Plus adding some `display:table-row` to create as many rows as you like

Answer (score 0):

You can set height for project name like this: **[Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/8202x060/4/)**

```
.project-name{
    height:40px;
    background-color:#ccc;
    display:block;
    overflow:hidden;
}
```

Comment: bad approach. as you have defined a fixed height with overflow:hidden.

Answer (score 0):

Add this to your CSS:

```css
.grid12-2:nth-child(6n+1)
{
    clear:both;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately I can only think `flexbox` would work here (barring some elaborate CSS table layout)....or a JS solution.

[**JSfiddle Demo**](https://jsfiddle.net/8202x060/7/)

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}
.grid12-2 {
  flex: 0 0 14.66%;
  background: plum;
  margin-bottom: 1%;
}
img {
  max-width: 100%;
}
.grid12-1,
.grid12-2,
.grid12-25,
.grid12-3,
.grid12-4,
.grid12-5,
.grid12-6,
.grid12-7,
.grid12-8,
.grid12-9,
.grid12-10,
.grid12-11,
.grid12-12,
.grid-full,
.grid-col2-sidebar,
.grid-col2-main {
  margin-left: 1%;
  margin-right: 1%;
}
.container {
  max-width: 1200px;
}
.container {
  max-width: 960px;
  width: 96%;
}
.container {
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="grid12-2 mobile-grid">
    <a class="open-popup-link" href="#popup-feu">
      <img src="http://dev.boutiquevalmont.com/media/wysiwyg/valmont/arts/thb3.jpg" />
      <p class="project-name">The Dialogue of Fire</p>
    </a>

  </div>

  <div class="grid12-2 mobile-grid">
    <a class="open-popup-link" href="#popup-feu">
      <img src="http://dev.boutiquevalmont.com/media/wysiwyg/valmont/arts/thb3.jpg" />
      <p class="project-name">The Dialogue of Fire</p>
    </a>

  </div>
  <div class="grid12-2 mobile-grid">
    <a class="open-popup-link" href="#popup-feu">
      <img src="http://dev.boutiquevalmont.com/media/wysiwyg/valmont/arts/thb3.jpg" />
      <p class="project-name">The Dialogue of FireFireFireFire</p>
    </a>

  </div>
  <div class="grid12-2 mobile-grid">
    <a class="open-popup-link" href="#popup-feu">
      <img src="http://dev.boutiquevalmont.com/media/wysiwyg/valmont/arts/thb3.jpg" />
      <p class="project-name">The Dialogue of Fire</p>
    </a>

  </div>
  <div class="grid12-2 mobile-grid">
    <a class="open-popup-link" href="#popup-feu">
      <img src="http://dev.boutiquevalmont.com/media/wysiwyg/valmont/arts/thb3.jpg" />
      <p class="project-name">The Dialogue of Fire</p>
    </a>

  </div>
  <div class="grid12-2 mobile-grid">
    <a class="open-popup-link" href="#popup-feu">
      <img src="http://dev.boutiquevalmont.com/media/wysiwyg/valmont/arts/thb3.jpg" />
      <p class="project-name">The Dialogue</p>
    </a>

  </div>
  <div class="grid12-2 mobile-grid">
    <a class="open-popup-link" href="#popup-feu">
      <img src="http://dev.boutiquevalmont.com/media/wysiwyg/valmont/arts/thb3.jpg" />
      <p class="project-name">The Dialogue of Fire</p>
    </a>

  </div>
  <div class="grid12-2 mobile-grid">
    <a class="open-popup-link" href="#popup-feu">
      <img src="http://dev.boutiquevalmont.com/media/wysiwyg/valmont/arts/thb3.jpg" />
      <p class="project-name">The Dialogue of Fire</p>
    </a>

  </div>
  <div class="grid12-2 mobile-grid">
    <a class="open-popup-link" href="#popup-feu">
      <img src="http://dev.boutiquevalmont.com/media/wysiwyg/valmont/arts/thb3.jpg" />
      <p class="project-name">The Dialogue of FireFireFireFire</p>
    </a>

  </div>
  <div class="grid12-2 mobile-grid">
    <a class="open-popup-link" href="#popup-feu">
      <img src="http://dev.boutiquevalmont.com/media/wysiwyg/valmont/arts/thb3.jpg" />
      <p class="project-name">The Dialogue of Fire</p>
    </a>

  </div>
  <div class="grid12-2 mobile-grid">
    <a class="open-popup-link" href="#popup-feu">
      <img src="http://dev.boutiquevalmont.com/media/wysiwyg/valmont/arts/thb3.jpg" />
      <p class="project-name">The Dialogue of Fire</p>
    </a>

  </div>
  <div class="grid12-2 mobile-grid">
    <a class="open-popup-link" href="#popup-feu">
      <img src="http://dev.boutiquevalmont.com/media/wysiwyg/valmont/arts/thb3.jpg" />
      <p class="project-name">The Dialogue</p>
    </a>

  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

please try this one:

```
.container {
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
}
```

[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/ivinraj/8202x060/8/)